# Magento: Indexing on temporary file

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Needed some advise from Magento Guru's

When we do indexing, we see that the site does not function well.
For example, when the indexing for category_product page is running, none of the category pages work. Or when the price index is working, there are issues with the add to cart.

We could do it in two ways:
1. Run a master-slave config and do the indexing on the slave setup
2. Make change in the code, so that the indexing is sone on temporary table and then copied into the main table.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an upgrade to 1.5, they updated the index process to stop using flat_catalog/product tables during the index process in order to address some of these issues (missing values).

I believe 1.7 also includes changes to the indexing process, but I can't say I've checked this out yet.